# Create a series of squares with horizontal scroll

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to create a parent container and a series of children.
Each child is a square. The children should be on the same single line and there should be a horizontal scroll.

This is the code:

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.square {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: tomato;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
</div>
```

As you can see, it doesn't work.
There isn't horizontal scroll and children are not `20x20px`...

Comment: once you fix the shrink issue, you will have the scroll issue (added a duplicate for it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [flex-shrink](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-shrink): 0 on the children of the flex container. This will stop the children from shrinking to fit the width of the parent:

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.square {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: tomato;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
</div>
```

> MDN:  If the size of all flex items is larger than the flex container, items shrink to fit according to flex-shrink.

Setting flex-shrink to 0 will counter this.

Answer (score 0):

Add `flex-shrink: 0;` to the `.square`. This means do not shrink the size:

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.square {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: tomato;
  margin-right: 5px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
</div>
```